# Valdidate and send HTML email with attachment

Tags: php, html

I have a half-working php contact form with html.
Half working is beacuse the validation isn't working, the mail will be send even if one of the fields is in an incorrect format. 
Second thing is that I want to add to that contact form the attachment the user uploaded (only one file).

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$EmailFrom = "Sap_Prio_Hash@lander.comsign";
$EmailTo = "chenf@comda.co.il";
$Subject = "Lead from Sap/Prio/Hash lander";
$Name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Name'])); 
$Email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Email'])); 
$Tel = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Tel']));
$Message = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Message']));

function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "Please check the field error:<br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['Tel']) ||
        !isset($_POST['Email']) ) {
        died('Error found in fields');       
    }

    $Tel = $_POST['Tel']; // required
    $Email = $_POST['Email']; // required
    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$Email)) {
    $error_message .= 'Email is incorrect<br />';
  }

    $string_exp = "/^[0-9 .'-]+$/";

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$Tel)) {
    $error_message .= 'Phone number is incorrect<br />';
  }

    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }

    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

// validation
$validationOK=true;
if (!$validationOK) {
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.htm\">";
  exit;
}

// prepare email body text
$Body = "";
$Body .= "Name: ";
$Body .= $Name;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Tel: ";
$Body .= $Tel;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Email: ";
$Body .= $Email;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Message: ";
$Body .= $Message;
$Body .= "\n";

// send email 
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$EmailFrom>");

// redirect to success page 
if ($success){
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=thanks.html\">";
}
else{
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.htm\">";
}
?>
```

The form in the html is a simple one:

```
<div id="formdiv">
    <form id='contactus' name="contactform" method="post" action="contacten.php">
        <input type="text" name="Pickpro" id="Pickpro" class="textbox" />
        <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" class="textbox" />
        <input type="text" name="Email" id="Text1" class="textbox" />
        <input type="text" name="Tel" id="Tel" class="textbox" />
        <input type="text" name="Message" id="Message" class="textbox" />
        <input type="file" class="file" id="attachment" />
        <input type="submit" id="send" title="שלח" value="" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Using `die()` isn't a good practice.

Comment: ok, so what would be a good practice? how should I validate the form?

Comment: Reading code like this always makes me wish I had an email address in a `.museum` domain.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly how do you expect your validation to work when you simply force it to be "ok" every time?

```
$validationOK=true;   <--- your validation never fails because of this
if (!$validationOK) {
```

And if you want to send attachments in that email, then don't use `mail()`. It's pathetically useless "use only in case of emergency" garbage. Use a proper mailer package, like PHPMailer or Swiftmailer. Both of those make sending mime emails+attachments trivial.